# Workbook on object oriented design (object model domain, system sequence diagrams, interaction diagrams)

Tags: oop, excel

Although I have a somewhat solid ground on object oriented theory and know how to build something as simple as a tetris / tic tac toe game in a "evolutive" design with no major trouble, I'd like to learn how to take the totally different approach of first designing the system and only them trying to implement it.

I am looking for something that'll teach me how to take a problem (for example, a tic tac toe game) and learn how to make its uml design (object domain model -> system sequence diagrams and finally [communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_diagram) diagrams).

I'm looking for something like a workbook that has a bit of theory, examples, exercises and solutions (if possible).

I know people generally recommend [UML and Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062) but I've had it in my OO course and found it awful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The famous coffee maker problem from Martin Fowler.

- [Coffee Maker](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/CoffeeMaker.pdf)
- [Another to look at](http://www.iei.liu.se/is/edu/courses/it-projekt---fordjupning/objektorienterad-analys-och-design/extra-material/1.452827/coffeebrewerdesign.pdf)
- [Interesting problem to solve without procedural code](http://www.xpteam.com/jeff/writings/objectcalisthenics.rtf) Jeff Bay mentioned it in this post: [OOD / OOP Etudes / Code exercises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310477/ood-oop-etudes-code-exercises)
- [Problems with solutions explained](http://www.itmaybeahack.com/book/oodesign-java-2.1/html/index.html). This is very good

Finally buy [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062) specifically for its treatment of the GRASP principles

Comment: Erm, I specifically said I used and didnt like that GRASP book :P

Comment: interesting. what did you not like? I've gone through at least 5 books and that is the best one I liked ;-)

Comment: devoured elysium - are you looking for more examples? was curious why this was not accepted?

Comment: The "another to look at" link is dead.

Comment: @hoogamaphone fixed the link

Comment: Sadly the coffee maker link is now dead.

Comment: Second link is now dead.

Comment: All the links are now dead!