# Object Oriented Design Practice Problems

Tags: oop

I've been developing almost exclusively C-code for the past few years.  I'm currently looking to brush up on my Object Oriented Design skills.  Can anyone recommend any resources that have a decent set of short object-oriented design problems with some possible solutions/analysis?  I'd ideally like something that was a small enough problem to sketch out and design in during a question in an interview that can be completed/analyzed in 15-30 minutes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at my answers to the below two posts

1. [Workbook on object oriented design (object model domain, system sequence diagrams, interaction diagrams)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501891/workbook-on-object-oriented-design-object-model-domain-system-sequence-diagrams/4502112#4502112)
2. [Software Design questions for Software Engineer Interview](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37275/software-design-questions-for-software-engineer-interview)

Comment: the second link is not working

Comment: TRY this:    https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182451/oo-design-related-questions-in-technical-interviews