# Is there any list of small projects for OOD/TDD practice?

Tags: oop

As title indicates, I'd like to practice OOD/TDD with different small projects. I guess I am what they call a dumb programmer and can't think of many small projects. In addition, I am not sure it would be good if I can think of that many projects because that means I've already thought about the project and it may not a good practice due to the advantage.

So could you let me know a list of small projects I can practice OOD/TDD. Thanks a lot.

Update: Thanks to @chelmertz I found [this Code Kata web site](http://codekata.pragprog.com/2007/01/code_kata_backg.html#more) provides with really good small projects for practice.

Comment: doing TDD for a website is always "fun". it tests your patience to test every layer of the website.

Comment: Possible google term: "code kata"

Comment: This question's answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890529/object-oriented-design-practice-problems

Comment: @Raynos I said small projects. ;-) As I am mainly asp.net developer, I agree with you though.

Comment: @chelmertz That's seems to be exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

blog engine, if that is too big, todo list app. Try to think of things that have a clearly defined set of boundries, are fairly simple problems, and could be of use to you later.

Comment: Have already practiced them and totally with you that they are good projects to exercise.

Answer (score 3):

Think of things in real life that you know well so that you will be able to answer the requirement-type questions. If you've done accounting in school for example create a simple accounting app. If you know cars maybe create a car maintenance app or inventory control system.

Comment: One problem is that I am already doing it for my work. So I want to diversify my domain knowledge too in this learning. But anyway, thanks for the good advice.